# Weights by name in Keras

Tags: keras

After training a model using Keras, I can get a list of weight arrays using:

```
myModel.get_weights()
```

or

```
myLayer.get_weights()
```

I'd like to know the names corresponding to each weight array.  I know how to do this indirectly by saving the model and parsing the HDF5 file but surely there must be a direct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 35):

Function `get_weights` returns a list of numpy arrays with no name information in them.

As for `Model.get_weights()`, it's just the concatenation of `Layer.get_weights()` for each one of the [flattened] layers.

However, `Layer.weights` gives direct access to the backend variables, and these, yes, may have a name. The solution then is to iterate through each weight of each layer, retrieving its `name` attribute.

An example with VGG16:

```py
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16


model = VGG16()

names = [weight.name for layer in model.layers for weight in layer.weights]
weights = model.get_weights()

for name, weight in zip(names, weights):
    print(name, weight.shape)
```

which outputs:

```
block1_conv1_W_6:0 (3, 3, 3, 64)
block1_conv1_b_6:0 (64,)
block1_conv2_W_6:0 (3, 3, 64, 64)
block1_conv2_b_6:0 (64,)
block2_conv1_W_6:0 (3, 3, 64, 128)
block2_conv1_b_6:0 (128,)
block2_conv2_W_6:0 (3, 3, 128, 128)
block2_conv2_b_6:0 (128,)
block3_conv1_W_6:0 (3, 3, 128, 256)
block3_conv1_b_6:0 (256,)
block3_conv2_W_6:0 (3, 3, 256, 256)
block3_conv2_b_6:0 (256,)
block3_conv3_W_6:0 (3, 3, 256, 256)
block3_conv3_b_6:0 (256,)
block4_conv1_W_6:0 (3, 3, 256, 512)
block4_conv1_b_6:0 (512,)
block4_conv2_W_6:0 (3, 3, 512, 512)
block4_conv2_b_6:0 (512,)
block4_conv3_W_6:0 (3, 3, 512, 512)
block4_conv3_b_6:0 (512,)
block5_conv1_W_6:0 (3, 3, 512, 512)
block5_conv1_b_6:0 (512,)
block5_conv2_W_6:0 (3, 3, 512, 512)
block5_conv2_b_6:0 (512,)
block5_conv3_W_6:0 (3, 3, 512, 512)
block5_conv3_b_6:0 (512,)
fc1_W_6:0 (25088, 4096)
fc1_b_6:0 (4096,)
fc2_W_6:0 (4096, 4096)
fc2_b_6:0 (4096,)
predictions_W_6:0 (4096, 1000)
predictions_b_6:0 (1000,)
```